# Accessing variable from MainActivity in other packages

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

I've been following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) to use location for a weather app. I've followed the instructions as specified for `MainActivity` but would like to use this location information for making API calls.

I've structured my app after a CodeLab involving RetroFit2 and Moshi. I've declared a `network` package and am working in a `ApiService` class contained therein. How can I access the location object defined in `MainActivity` from within `ApiService`?

com.example.app.MainActivity:

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
}
```

com.example.app.network.ApiService:

```
// how to access fusedLocationClient here?

private const val BASE_URL =
    "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&current_weather=true"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're some ways you could accomplish this. The easiest one is have this API call on the MainActivityViewModel, so you could send as a parameter all the information you want. It would be something like this:

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     // ...
     fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

     viewModel.makeCall(fusedLocationCient) 
}
```

And on the viewModel

```
ViewModel: ViewModel() {

    fun makeCall(fusedLocationClient: LocationClient) {
        
        // I don't know how you created this ApiService, 
        // but you should access it here
        ApiService().makeCall(fusedLocationClient)

    }

}
```

The second one (don't think you're gonna need this) is to have a Singleton with this Location data, and get it on the class you want. You could use Koin to inject these classes.